# Why is my JS DOM manipulation result undefined and not changing the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to change the images in my HTML by clicking upon them.

When I log the result in the console, it logs "undefined."  I also have no effect when I click on the images and see no changes to the HTML otherwise.

```
const flipAllCards = function () {
    for(const card of cards) {
        card.innerHTML.replace(`<img src="img/cardback.jpeg" alt="">`)
    }
};
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
flipAllCards();
function assignImages () {
    for(const card of cards) {
        const cardName = card.id;
        const imageName = `${cardName}.jpeg`;
        function flipCard (card) {
            card.innerHTML.replace(`<img src="img/${imageName}" alt="">`);
        }
        console.log(flipCard(card));
        card.addEventListener('click', flipCard(card));
    }
}
assignImages();
```

And the HTML:

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="card" id = "agentbrown"><img src="img/agentbrown.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "agentjones"><img src="img/agentjones.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "agentsmith"><img src="img/agentsmith.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "spoonboy"><img src="img/spoonboy.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "switch"><img src="img/switch.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "trinity"><img src="img/trinity.jpeg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Of course it is logging undefined because you aren't returning anything.

Comment: what `cards` is equal to?

Comment: @deathangel908 "const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");"

Comment: `card.addEventListener('click', flipCard(card));` <-- this function is being invoked immediately, not on click. So it is essentially the same as `('click', undefined)` since `flipCard` has no return. You need to use an anonymous function here

Comment: Where is `flipAllCards()` defined? Also I see you are using some es6 syntax that most likely isnt supported in browser unless you have polyfills or newer chrome... just throwing that out there.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine const flipAllCards = function () {
    for(const card of cards) {
        card.innerHTML.replace(`<img src="img/cardback.jpeg" alt="">`)
    }
};

Answer (score 1):

First issue, yes it is printing undefined because you aren't actually returning anything. When you try to log on something that isn't being returned it is inherently going to be undefined. In the snippet below I edited it to return the innerHTML so you can see the output.

Second issue, you don't wanna use innerHTML.replace if you are replacing the content you would want to just do innerHTML =  the new content.

.replace is trying to replace a specific subset of characters, not replace the content.

Finally, you are calling your click immediately because of how you are passing it. You need to wrap it in an anonymous function so that it is only called on click.

Also, in the below snippet, I am appending the word WAFFLES to each of your changes so you can actually see the change.

```js
const flipAllCards = function () {
    for(const card of cards) {
        card.innerHTML = `<img src="img/cardback.jpeg" alt="">`;
    }
};
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");
function assignImages () {
    for(const card of cards) {
        const cardName = card.id + "WAFFLES";
        const imageName = `${cardName}.jpeg`;
        function flipCard (card) {
            card.innerHTML = (`<img src="img/${imageName}" alt="">`);
            return card.innerHTML;
        }
        console.log(flipCard(card));
        card.addEventListener('click', function(){flipCard(card)});
    }
}
assignImages();
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="card" id = "agentbrown"><img src="img/agentbrown.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "agentjones"><img src="img/agentjones.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "agentsmith"><img src="img/agentsmith.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "spoonboy"><img src="img/spoonboy.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "switch"><img src="img/switch.jpeg" alt=""></div>
    <div class="card" id = "trinity"><img src="img/trinity.jpeg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Also edited your flipAllCards function because it was wrong as well. When replacing innerHTML you want to just use = not .replace. What you currently have is trying to say: replace the content

You can see a better representation of this below.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('test');
// THIS WON'T UPDATE
element.innerHTML.replace('I love waffles!', 'juice is terrible');


// THIS WILL UPDATE

element.innerHTML = 'juice is amazing with waffles';
```

```html
<div id="test">
    I love waffles!
<div>
```

Comment: The console returns an error at the anonymous function: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {".

Comment: @Thomas more than likely you typed something in wrong. There is no error in the logs.

Comment: Thank you.  I fixed that problem, but the images still don't have have any DOM manipulation.

Comment: @Thomas what do you mean? Are the images not replacing? Right now its probably because you are using the id's but the id's match the img src already.

Comment: Does this mean the flipAllCards function isn’t executing? What may be preventing the cardback.jpeg image from appearing before I click on the images?

Comment: @Thomas I added an additional update earlier, you had the same innerHTML.replace issue.

Comment: I also changed that, and I still had no image change.